# GET Params - & and ? in one character?

Tags: php, url, get, url-parameters

So just a quick thought and I understand that there are millions of ways around this 'problem' but I was wondering if there is a character or format for both initiating and separating GET parameters. Let me explain:

I am redirecting the user to a link defined as a variable but adding on a parameter at the end like so:

```
Header("Location: ".$link."&err=1");
```

The problem is, some of these links ($link) will contain GET params and some will not. If the link does not already contain GET parameters, '&' will not work as an initiator.

```
Header("Location: page&err=1");
```

And if the link does already contain parameters, '?' will not work as a separating character.

```
Header("Location: page?val=123?err=1");
```

So again, I know there are many ways around this and I'm not lookign for someone to code a simple check for me but I'm curious about the link formatting aspect and I can't find anything through my own research. I'm honestly expecting that the answer is 'not possible' but I'm intrigued enough to ask now, thanks.

Comment: look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#parameters

Answer (score 2):

No.

`?` starts the query string.

`&` and `;` separate key=value pairs in application/x-www-form-urlencoded data which is the format most back ends expect. (`;` hasn't got as good a level of support).

Comment: Yeah thought so, thanks anyways :)

Answer (score -1):

Will [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) not work?

Specifically `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);`

[http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) could also be useful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).